# Is this a counterexample to ΔU = 0 J for isothermal processes?

Tags: thermodynamics

In class, I have learned that for **isothermal** processes the following is true at all times.

$$\Delta U=q+w=0\text{ J}$$

But suppose I lift an object against the force of gravity. Then I (the surroundings) have done work on the object (the system) without exchanging heat (neglecting friction).

Now, I claim that because some nonzero work has been done on the system, and no heat has been exchanged, the change in internal energy is nonzero:

$$\Delta U=w\neq0\text{ J}$$

Are my assumptions about internal energy incorrect or is there something totally wrong about my approach?

Comment: For isothermal process $\Delta U =0$ is true **only** for ideal gases. Isn't mechanical work considered for gases only, not sure?

Comment: If I had assumed that initially, I think this question would still valid because I could be lifting the gas, too. Edit: I see your edit now, I am not sure about it either.

Comment: Adiabatic, isothermal expansion of ideal gases must be free expansion...

Comment: Sure, but even if it doesn't expand, work can be done on it as I'm showing in my question

Comment: This was cross-posted to [physics.se] at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545690. @awalllllll, which site would you like your question to appear on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation you cite calls for the use of the more general form of the first law of thermodynamics (which I assume your textbook provides), given by $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=q+w$$where KE is the organized kinetic energy of the system and PE is the potential energy.  Applying this to the problem at hand gives $$\Delta (PE)=w$$and the change in internal energy is zero.  So the thing that was wrong with your approach was not using the proper form of the first law.

Comment: Is $\Delta U=q+w=0\text{ J}$ valid only for gaseous system?

Comment: @Zenix No.  Even a gaseous system can experience a change in kinetic energy and/or gravitational potential energy.

Comment: I have always seen $\Delta U=q+w=0\text{ J}$... ;(

Comment: So here U is *internal energy* whereas KE and PE are the energy of the system with respect to an external reference frame (ie the PE and KE of the internal reference frame)?

Comment: @zenix Get yourself a decent textbook.

Comment: @BuckThorn Yes.  U includes the random kinetic energy of the molecules and the potential energy of the molecular interactions (the latter for the case of a non-ideal gas).